# How to detect if text domain is already loaded?

Tags: localization

Without going into a lot of details, I have a multiple custom plugins within a multisite that share files outside of its original plugin folders. These plugins all work in conjunction with each other and can be installed separately or all at once depending on the functionality the site needs. These plugins share common files/resources that are located in a separate folder within the wp-contents directory.
My question is can I insert the text domain file within this shared folder and have all the plugins use the same text domain name. Then within each plugin call the `load_plugin_domain()` that will look into the shared folder for the files needed. However, do I need to detect if the text domain has already been loaded before calling load_plugin_domain()? Or can I just ad `load_plugin_domain()` within all the plugins and have it point to the same text domain and files?
I know it is confusing to explain and please don't down vote based on this...give me a chance to give more details if needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that I didb't understand the setup ;), but it doesn't matter as the lower level functions (`load_textdomain` IIRC) will check if a translation file is already loaded and will not load it again, therefor you can use the same file to include many translations,  and call the loading function as many times as you wish.